# gradient layer in Swift UITableView

Tags: swift, uitableview, gradient

I want to create a gradient background layer in each row of a UITableView in Swift. In the cellForRowAt function I have this piece of code to draw the gradient layer.

```
guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? PlayerTableViewCell else { fatalError("The dequeued cell is not an instance of PlayerTableViewCell") }

// set background color for the cell
let newLayer = CAGradientLayer()
newLayer.colors = [UIColor.black.cgColor, UIColor.darkGray.cgColor ]
newLayer.frame = cell.frame
cell.layer.addSublayer(newLayer)
cell.layer.insertSublayer(newLayer, at: 0)
```

When I run this code, only the first entry in the table has the gradient layer, the other cells have the default background. 
Do I need to add something?

[Missing background gradient color in table cells](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d9DVr.png)

Comment: were our answers able to resolve your issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the `gradientLayer` does not update its bounds when the frame of the superview changes - so when the superview changes its frame, the `gradientLayer` will still keep the same bounds. You need to update its bounds in `layoutSubviews`.

I would go with @Jay's answer, but there are some issues there:

```
var gradientLayer: CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()


override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

    // insert it only once
    gradientLayer.colors = [UIColor.black.cgColor, UIColor.darkGray.cgColor ]
    contentView.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)

}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    // here we just need to update the frame
    gradientLayer.frame = contentView.frame
}
```

I have tested it and it works just fine (well, @Jay's answer seems to be working too for that matter).

Comment: I like your answer better, but can you explain what are the issues with my answer, for my knowledge? :D

Comment: @Jay each time the cell is laid out, you create a new layer and add it to the existing layers.. I guess normally it would not change a visible issue, but even then it is at least redundant

Comment: @Jay but you were first here nonetheless, I'm gonna leave you an upvote, since your answer points to a right direction :-)

Answer (score 4):

Why not add it within the subclass of the cell? This way you can also remove it in the prepareForReuse as well, so you aren't adding multiples to the cell?

```
var newLayer:CAGradientLayer!

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    //Code to insert the gradient here.
    newLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    newLayer.frame = contentView.frame
    newLayer.colors = [UIColor.black.cgColor, UIColor.darkGray.cgColor ]
    contentView.layer.insertSublayer(newLayer, at: 0)
}
```